# Why count() doesn't work but size() does in Pandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, count, pandas

I have a point and a polygon data and in this line I'm simply making a spatial join and group its output to count incidents per area. Currently this line works but I don't understand why it works. I came up with this line online after not being able to group by and summarize in Pandas.

I'm trying to understand this line and why `count()` doesn't work but `size().reset_index()` works (and `size()` doesn't work without `reset_index()`)

```py
pz["INCIDENTS"] = gpd.sjoin(graf, pz, how="inner", predicate="within").groupby("NAME").size().reset_index(name="incidentsPerZone")["incidentsPerZone"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work? Size and count are different, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas